# Alternative installation of recent Julia 1.7.3 without MacPorts

Tags: install, python, macports

Usually, I used to install software on `High Sierra` via `MacPorts`.

Unfortunately, the port `Julia V1.7.3`, is broken recently such that a standard installation via `sudo port install Julia` does not work anymore.

Is it save to try an alternative installation via [julialang.org](https://julialang.org/downloads/) or would such a "mixed" installation destroy some internal links/paths of the present `MacPorts` installations?

Comment: Did you report a bug to MacPorts so that it could be fixed?  How does it "not work"?

Comment: @Marc: yes I have added a MacPorts ticket and it seems that this "problem" holds also for other OS versions. Unfortunately, no change since two or more weeks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be OK if

1. You have not installed any ports dependent on Julia via macports
2. Where the new Julia is installed is on the PATH before macports.

Even if 1 does not hold you are probably OK